# global variable from Project1.cpp accesible in Unit1.cpp

Tags: c++builder

How to declare a global variable in Project1.cpp and read it in Unit1.cpp ?
This question is about C++ Builder

Comment: FYI: Doing this is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Sharing non-const global variables between source files is almost always a recipe for awful unmaintainable code, and thus should be avoided.  You should find a different way to achieve whatever it is you want to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `extern` keyword in Unit1.cpp to refer the declaration from Project1.cpp.

For example, if in Project1.cpp you have

```
// Global variable

int myGlobalVar;
```

then in Unit1.cpp you should have

```
extern int myGlobalVar;
```

However, this practice is questionable and should be avoided. Important programming principles like modularization and decoupling can be denied by the usage of the global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to do something like this?

In Project1.h, declare a variable in the public area.

```
public  // User declarations
__fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
double MyVar;
```

Then include Project1.h in Unit1.cpp and then MyVar can be accessed as

```
Form1->MyVar
```

Comment: Which works, by the way, because Form1 is a global variable, created in Unit1.cpp, and referenced using extern in Unit1.h, just as in mircea's answer, only using TForm* instead of int